# D3.remove() is not working properly with c3-axis (I don't want to hide it)

Tags: d3.js, c3

I must remove the elements for the axis because I don't want to have empty space. I have to fit the graph in a panel.

[image]

I'm trying something like:

[image]

```
d3.select("g.c3-axis .c3-axis-y").remove();
d3.select("g.c3-axis-x").remove();
```

I printed this following selection in my console and it's all right but the remove doesn't work:

```
d3.select("svg").select(".c3-axis-x").selectAll("*").remove();
```

No results! What's the mistake ? I think that when I launch the function the chart is not completely generated, but I can't find a good solution to achieve the style desiderated.

Comment: `d3.select(".c3-axis-x").remove();` doesn't work?

Comment: No, but maybe it is not the right way to achieve the result. Do you have any suggestions to delete the empty to fit it in the bootstrap panel ?

Comment: To be honest I don't see a working example of the problem so can only speculate how to help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the result in a different way, I fixed the padding for the axis in the chart.

[image]

```
axis: 
        {
            x: 
            {

                type: 'timeseries',
                tick: 
                {
                    format : "%d-%m-%y"
                },
                show: false,
    padding : 
                {
                    bottom : 0,
                    left: 0, 
                    right: 0
                }

            },
            y: 
            {

                min: 0,
                padding : 
                {
                    bottom : 0,
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0
                },
                tick: 
                {
                    values: [[0], [maxs]],  
                    format:  function (d) { return d3.format(',f')(d) +' kWh/h' }
                },
                show: false
            }
        },
```